# Как правильно написать realloc для массива структур?

Tags: c, структуры, c++

Проблема заключается в следующем:

Когда я первый раз попадаю в функцию addItem и делаю в ней realloc указателя на структуру, а потом еще присваиваю значения, то после выхода из функции я вижу эти значения.
Когда я второй раз попадаю в функцию, проделываю эти же действия, то после этого у меня отображаются значения после первого раза, а от второго раза остаются только 0.
По задумке, после каждой итерации у меня должен пополняться элементами массив за счет realloс, но почему-то не работает.

realloc происходит в методе EnterData.

P.S. Не пугайтесь. Полный листинг я выложил лишь для того, мало ли кто-нибудь захочет скомпилировать прогу...
Если кто-нибудь захочет скомпилировать программу и посмотреть на результаты, то нужно вбить 0, а потом какие-то данные.

```
#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <tchar.h>
#else
typedef char _TCHAR;
#define _tmain main
#endif

#define SIZE 10
 struct Item{
 int key;
 int release;
 char *info;
};

void addItem(struct Item *,int*);
void deleteItem(struct Item *,int*);
void searchItem(struct Item *,int);
int enterData(int*,int*,char*,struct Item*,int);
int CheckKey(int ,struct Item *,int);
int CheckRelease(int ,int ,struct Item *,int);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
struct Item *table;
int ctrl,n=0,i;
void (*P[4])(struct Item *,int*)={addItem,deleteItem,searchItem};
table=malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
for (;;)
{ 
    puts("0 add\n1 delete \n2 search \n");
    scanf("%d",&ctrl);
    if (ctrl>5) 
    {
        break;  
    }
    (*P[ctrl])(table,&n);
    for (i=0; i<=n-1; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",table[i].key);
    }
}
return 0;
}
void addItem(struct Item *table,int *n)
{
int key,release;
char *info=malloc(sizeof(char)*50);
 if (*n==SIZE)
 {
  puts("Table is full. can not continue \n");
  return;
 }
 if(enterData(&key,&release,info,table,*n))
 {
(*n)++;
table=realloc(table,sizeof(struct Item)*(*n));
table[*n-1].key=key;
table[*n-1].release=release;
table[*n-1].info=info;
}
}

int enterData(int *key,int *release, char *info,struct Item *table,int n)
{
int a;
puts("Enter key: ");
scanf("%d",key);
if (CheckKey(*key,table,n)==2) {
puts("This item already exists. The number of releases exhausted");
return 0;
}
if (CheckKey(*key,table,n)==1) {
puts("This item already exists. You can add 1 realese");
}
puts("\n Enter release: ");
do
{
scanf("%d",release);
}
while (CheckRelease(*key,*release ,table,n)==0);
puts("\n Enter info(50 chars): \n");
fflush(stdin);
gets(info);
return 1;
}

int CheckKey(int key,struct Item *table,int n)
{

int i,cnt=0;
if (n==0) {
return 0;   
}
for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
if(table[i].key==key)
    {
        cnt++;
    }
}
return cnt;
}
int CheckRelease(int key,int release ,struct Item *table,int n)
{
int i;
if (n==0) {
return 1;   
}
for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++)
{
if(table[i].key==key)
    {
        if (table[i].release==release) 
        {
          puts("Thies element have this release. Enter another release.");
          return 0; 
        }
        return 1;
        }
    }
}

void deleteItem(struct Item *table,int *key)
{

}

void searchItem(struct Item *table,int key)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас содержимое указателя `table` (размещенный в main) не меняется.

При вызове `(*P[ctrl])(table,&n);` в функцию, например, `addItem()` передается *копия* `table`, которую и меняет `realloc()`.

Передавайте адрес `table` и меняйте `*table`. Т.е.

```
  ...
  (*P[ctrl])(&table,&n);
  ...
  void addItem(struct Item **table,int *n) {
    ...
    if(enterData(&key,&release,info,*table,*n)) {
    ...
    *table=realloc(*table,sizeof(struct Item)*(*n));
    (*table)[*n-1].key=key;
    ...
```

Аналогичным образом измените и остальной код.

Comment: Хм... А мне казалось, что, передавая указатель, я могу все что угодно с ним делать...

Т.е. получается, если я передаю простой указатель, то могу менять значения только в ранее выделенной памяти, а что бы поменять сам указатель, нужен указатель на указатель?

Где бы про это можно почитать, желательно на русском?

Comment: Наверное, в любом нормальном учебнике по Си (например, в K&R).